# How to use Elasticsearch search templates in multi search (_msearch) API?

Tags: templates, search, elasticsearch

Is it possible to use registered search templates in a multi search api (_msearch) request?
If so, how?

I tried giving the following query in a body.

```
POST /_msearch
{"index":"index1","type":"type1"}
{"template":{"id":"template_1"},"params":{"a":1, "b":2}}
```

But that leads to the error:

```
Parse Failure [No parser for element [template]]
```

I tried wrapping everything in a query:

```
POST /_msearch
{"index":"index1","type":"type1"}
{"query":{"template":{"id":"template_1"},"params":{"a":1, "b":2}}}
```

and POSTing to _msearch/template, but these didn't work either.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently supported but they have an open enhancement request for it.  [Add template support to _msearch #10885](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10885)

Answer (score 0):

This feature was added in 2016, here are the docs for multi-search using template for 6.8 (currently the oldest ES version supported):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/multi-search-template.html